# Best way to deploy and Schedule Deep Learning Model

Tags: deep-learning, model, keras

I am looking for best way to deploy my Deep Learning application which does the following:

1. Fetches data from `BigQuery`
2. Finds `anomaly` (based on trained model)
3. Throws the output in a `mysql` database.
   I want this program to run everyday on a specific time like a cronjob.

Any lead on how can I achieve this deployment, other than using a `cronjob` because it will be unnecessary to pay for the time and resources when it will not be in use.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is an engineering question, not a stats question. I think it belongs on a different forum.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to schedule a task, you will **necessary** have to pay for a compute ressource, but you do not necessary pay for a ressource which can run your task.

To be more clear: take a small remote instance (full time) to a cloud service using a cronjob which will create an ephemeral instance (bigger) where your task will be executed.

If you want a tool to help you, take a look at [Airflow](http://airflow.apache.org/)